# Can a sorcerer use the Quickened Spell metamagic option to cast cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic, cantrips

Considering that in higher levels, cantrips deal more damage than L2 spells (especially if you dip 2 levels of Warlock, with EB + Hex + Agonizing Blast), I'm wondering whether it's more efficient for an (MC) Sorcerer to use L2 Slots to power Quickened (EB) cantrips.

The Quickened Spell metamagic option says:

> When you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 action, you can spend 2 sorcery points to change the casting time to 1 bonus action for this casting.

The idea would be to Quicken EB a few times (or in a big fight, until you run out of SP), and at the end of the fight (or during, if needed), convert L2 slots to more SP. Since you keep these until a long rest, you can basically stock up in SP in between fights.

Can a sorcerer use the Quickened Spell metamagic option to cast cantrips?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, as long as the cantrip has a casting time of 1 Action

Most cantrips require an action to cast. As such, you can certainly quicken them. So any 1 Action casting time cantrip will be usable, such as Eldritch Blast in this question.

However, PHB p. 202 states:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You
>   must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell,
>   provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action
>   this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same
>   turn, except for a **cantrip** with a casting time of 1 action.

Thankfully, if you are planning on casting two cantrips per turn, you are more than able to do this effectively, **as they are not restricted by the same restriction as regular spells.**

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use Quicken Spell to cast cantrips. As you've noted, Quicken Spell requires a spell with a casting time of one action. Cantrips are defined as:

> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, without using
>   a spell slot and without being prepared in advance.
>   Repeated practice has fixed the spell in the caster’s mind
>   and infused the caster with the magic needed to produce
>   the effect over and over. A cantrip’s spell level is 0.

There is nothing here that would prevent cantrips from being usable with Quicken Spell, so as long as the cantrip in question has a casting time of one action (which Eldritch Blast does), you can use Quicken Spell to cast it as a bonus action.

You've probably noticed, but I'll point out for readers, that this means you can cast two Eldritch Blasts in a single turn, since the restriction on bonus action spells is:

> You can’t cast another spell during the same
>   turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.