# Can a Sorcerer-3/Warlock-2 cast a subtle healing word and a quickened eldritch blast in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, actions, sorcerer, metamagic

I want to know if I'm understanding things right - that this set of actions is valid and doable.

I'm also using [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/can-you-use-quickened-spell-to-cast-cantrips) as reference to prove I can quicken Eldritch Blast.

Assuming a Sorcerer 3 (Any) and a Warlock 2 (Celestial - as per Xanathar's Guide), could a character that has taken quickened spell and subtle spell metamagic at this level do the following.

Character CHAMAN charges forward, moving his speed towards a distant ally in trouble. He then looks at ALLYMAN and heals him silently using Healing Word from a range (gained via Celestial pact), and then turns his gaze to an ENEMYTHING rushing at ALLYMAN and quickens an Eldritch Blast to blow them away. (All in one turn.)

Mechanically this is:

1. Move
2. Cast Healing Word + Subtle Spell Metamagic on ally
3. Cast Eldritch Blast + Quicken Spell Metamagic on enemy

---

- 1 spell slot used
- 3 spell points used
- 1 turn used

EDIT: I'm going to leave the rest of the question as-is because some of the answers will be wonky without it, but as people have noted I was wrong thinking that I had healing word with Celestial. Cure Wounds works in its place for my intent.

Comment: Are you a divine soul sorcerer? If not, how do you have access to *healing word*?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Everything makes more sense if he is trying to use Cure Wounds. Did you mean Cure Wound Ethan?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### It'll work, just not the way you described.

#### Why your plan won't work

In your plan, you are trying to cast **two bonus action spells**. One is a standard cast of a Bonus Action (Healing Word) and the other is a spell converted from Action to Bonus Action via Quicken (Eldritch Blast.)

Unfortunately, [you only get one bonus action per turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn).

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Therefore your original plan is both not playable via the rules and is a waste of resources. Take the easier path below!

#### Simplify your plan

The spellcasting rules on page 202 of the PHB state (emphasis mine):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

[Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spells#HealingWord) is already a Bonus Action spell, so that fulfills your Bonus Action cast.

You can them simply cast Eldritch Blast with your Action and all is good. Quicken Spell is not necessary.

#### But how did you get Healing Word?

Healing Word is not a Warlock option, even as a Celestial. Nor is it on the Sorcerer or Warlock spell lists. As [Xirema](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122816/23024) noted, only the Divine Soul Sorcerer has this, so you'd need that to be your Sorcerer dip (and can only be that dip) in order for this to work as planned.

You could also take the Magic Initiate Feat and pick up Healing Word (if you do, I'd suggest taking it from the Bard spell list to keep your CHA modifier.)

#### Your actual usage

1. Bonus Action Healing Word (1 spell slot + 1 spell point for Subtle)
2. Action to cast Eldritch Blast (no cost)
3. Above happens in 1 turn

Comment: It doesn't work for two reasons - both because you only get one bonus action and because healing word is not a cantrip and therefore can't be cast in the same turn as a quickened spell.

Comment: @BenBarden The misunderstanding of Healing Word's casting time is the root of the problem.  All other issues stem from that.

Answer (score 13):

Something additional that the other answers overlooked:

*Healing Word* is not a spell that Warlocks gain access to, Celestial-patron or not. In the combination you've described, *Healing Word* is only accessible to a Divine Soul Sorcerer, which means the sorcerer part of your multiclass can't just be "any" sorcerer; it has to be a divine soul for your combo to work as you expect it to.

It's possible you meant "Healing Light", which is the class feature that Celestial Warlocks gain, but it can't be altered by metamagic because it's not a spell, so you'd be limited to casting it as-is as a bonus action, without eliminating the verbal/somatic components.

## But here's some Good News...

You would still be able to cast this combo, since Healing Light only requires a bonus action, which makes it fully compatible with casting Eldritch Blast in the same turn. In fact, because *Healing Light* doesn't have Somatic or Verbal components, you could get all the benefits of the combo you described, without needing to multiclass as a Sorcerer at all: just use Healing Light instead of Healing Word. No Spell Slots consumed, no Sorcery Points consumed, no inefficient multiclassing needed, and it can be used as many times per long rest as 1 + your warlock level. **And**, if you're dissatisfied by the relatively low healing power of Healing Word, you can rest assured in the knowledge that the healing power of Healing Light is significantly more potent, if you're willing to use extra dice on each roll.

Comment: You may want to note that they can still cast Eldritch Blast if they do the Healing Light (which doesn't have somatic/verbal components to begin with because it's just a class feature.)

Answer (score 10):

## No, this doesn't work, but you can do something equivalent

You only get one bonus action per round, and since Healing Word is already a Bonus Action you can't cast Healing Word + Quickened Eldritch Blast (they both require a Bonus Action).

You can cast Eldritch Blast using your normal Action, and Healing Word (Subtle) with your Bonus Action just fine though, using only 1 Sorcery Point. Note that this only works if the spell you cast with your normal Action is a cantrip because of the following rule:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, **except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action**.

So you can cast Eldritch Blast + Healing Word, but not Magic Missile + Healing Word.